# Syntax of an Overflow Check in C (Example From OpenBSD)

Tags: malloc, overflow

I was reading the OpenBSD manual pages and came across an example of an overflow check for the `malloc` function. I am confused about the logic behind the `if` condition `if(size && num > SIZE_MAX / size)`. I thought the first part `size && num` would evaluate as either true or false, resulting in a comparison of either 1 or 0 with `SIZE_MAX / size`. Can someone explain this logic?

```c
size_t num, size;
...

/* Check for size_t overflow */
if (size && num > SIZE_MAX / size)
    errc(1, EOVERFLOW, "overflow");

if ((p = malloc(num * size)) == NULL)
    err(1, NULL);
```